# Eclipse trouble when trying to add new class

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an Android application.

I want to add a new class, subclassing java.lang.Object. This is my procedure:

File > New > Class
Chosing package
Typing a name ("DBCommunicator")
Clicking "Finish"

Nothing happens!

I'm working on a Mac so the Finish button is blinking as when enabled, but nothing happens when I click it. There's even no warning or notification in the upper part of the window as it uses to when there's a problem.

[image: New Class dialog]

I'm choosing all different check boxes and radio buttons but still nothing happens.
Anyone knows what I'm missing?

-- UPDATE --

The add-a-class dialog (the one in the picture) does not disappear, and I am right clicking in the right place / selecting the right folder/class when clicking File > New > Class

Comment: Does the create-a-class window go away when you click Finish?

Comment: Do you right click on the package? Or on the whole project?

Comment: No, the add-a-class window does not disappear, and I am right clicking both on the project, the package, the src folder and on an existing java file in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a confusion when you are creating New Class. Please observe that Class file has been created in some other project as that project might be selected in Package Explorer while you are creating new Class.

To get rid of such problems, you need right click on the package or Project in which you want to create class and then go for New option in menu and then Class file.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The add-a-class window doesn't even disappear.